# Flutter audio_service set rating

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

I am using audio_service for background music with just_audio. Everything is working fine.

I want to add heart rating style. When user play a song in playlist, there will be option to press heart icon to add into favourite list. In MediaItem there is Rating property. I can set the rating before load into queue. Now I want to set the rating for current song in queue. There is no way to set the rating.

I try to update the queue item as follow, it is not update either.I check in queue and item in queue is updated but not in playlist is not updated.

```
@override
Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    int index = queue.value.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaItem.id);
    if (index != -1) {
        queue.value[index] = mediaItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing to set state?

Comment: I don't think so. I can play the song in list and can move previous and next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I want to closed this question. It is happing because I need to change the one of the ValueNotifier.value.